# Unbiased Shuffling with Large Number of Duplicates

Tags: algorithm, random, permutation, shuffle, fisher-yates-shuffle

The Fisher–Yates algorithm generates unbiased random permutations of a finite sequence. The running time is proportional to the number elements being shuffled.

I want to shuffle a few non-zero elements with a large number of zero elements.

Implementing the Fisher–Yates algorithm with a list would lead to the shuffling process taking too long and requiring too much storage. Most steps in the Fisher--Yates algorithm would simply switch the position of duplicate zero elements.

Does there exists a random shuffle (or alternative) algorithm that:

1. Leads to unbiased permutations
2. Does not require the shuffling and storing of all duplicate elements

Comment: There are approximately 1e4 to 1e6 zero elements per non-zero element.

Comment: With that kind of distribution you could distribute the non-zero values at random indexes. In the rare case of collision, just retry.

Comment: @trincot A better estimate of the number of non-zero elements is perhaps 1e2 to 1e6. I have more than enough non-zero elements that collision are an issue. In fact, your suggestion of removing samples with collisions is the algorithm I am trying to find an alternative to. As the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) illustrates, collision become almost inevitable for systems with large number of elements (even if the probability of a single collision remains small).

Comment: What is the array size?

Comment: Currently the array size is 1e4 to 1e8, but I would prefer to not to use an array of this size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a Fisher-Yates shuffle produces a random permutation, its inverse is also a random permutation:

1. For i=1 to n-1:

   1. choose a random number j in [0,i]
   2. swap elements i and j

In this algorithm, though, if you have m non-zero elements, and you start with all of them at the end, then the first n-m iterations are guaranteed to be swapping zeros, so you can just skip those.

Use a hash map instead of an array if you want to avoid storing all the zero elements.

Comment: I will check if this solution works.

Comment: I see now that your algorithm is referred to as the "inside-out" Fisher–Yates shuffle in Wikipedia.

Comment: @LodinEllingsen Does the Fisher-Yates algorithm guarantee all possible permutations are generated before repetitions take place?

Comment: @user2987773 No. The Fisher-Yates algorithm creates a completely new unbiased sample where each possible permutation is equally likely (including those previously generated).